# Best Method for Identifying Broken Ellipses

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying to identify ellipses in these pictures for a long time now for a project I'm working on. At the moment I'm trying a new method with a bit of success. I blur the image then subtract the original from it. After that I threshold that image which is how I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WKi1.jpg

I've been trying a few methods but have had pretty much no success with any of them. I can't get any more of the noise removed without compromising the quality of the ellipses I have found, but the ellipses I want to find seem to be decently defined.

If anyone has an idea on where I can go now I'd love to hear it.

Thanks,
Andy

edit:

Original Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZOER.jpg

The main method I've tried so far using an adaptive threshold on the image then fitting an ellipse around each of the contours I find after that. It works quite well in one set of images, but performs very poorly in this set. I can see my current method working well in both I get it right.

How well it works with old images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIO7S.jpg

How well it works with the new (more relevant to the program) images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7bW3.jpg

Comment: In these pictures?  What pictures?

Comment: Are these ellipses as in [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) or [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) or perhaps [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse)?

Comment: You might want to also post your original image before you performed the blur and thresholding. There may be methods that work better on those.

Comment: Also, you might want to list the methods you said you tried, and perhaps also post the results. This will help others determine which method already do not work without trying them, or perhaps tell you how to improve on them. Also, by looking at your result and code, we may be able to tell you whether your code has bugs.

Comment: You might also want to provide us with the constraints associated with your problem. E.g., do you know beforehand how many ellipses there will be? Do you have any restriction on the running time?

Comment: I've updated the post. The images are all going to have the same basic format - a round area with eggs usually clustered within it. The eggs are also about the same shape usually, which is why I though ellipse detection would be the best method. The problem is that the dark part inside the egg is often the part that gets picked out because it has more contrast, but I need the clear shell part to be included.

Comment: We don't know how many ellipses there will be, running time isn't a huge constraint but it would be best to keep it quite quick i.e. sub 5 seconds